# Can not make cache safe url

Tags: url, web-parts

I am working with Sharepoint 2007 and VS 2008. I created a web part with user control which refrences some external files (js,css and images). I deployed both the web part and the external files (files in 12 hive folder structure). When i try to use to web part I get the following error.

> Cannot make a cache safe URL for
>   "/DatePicker/JS/JsDatePick.min.1.3.js", file not found. Please verify
>   that the file exists under the layouts directory.

Though the js file exists in layout folder.

Please help. Thanks.